# How to make a value to exist once in a column and allow duplicate for other values in doctrine entity

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I am working on a symfony 2.8 project using doctrine as ORM.

I have an entity called Debt with field `Paid` (boolean).

My problem is I want that `"Paid"` field to be set to  `false` only one time but to set to `true` multiple times.

I know `Unique` constraints and `UniqueEntity` validator, but these methods and designed only for unique entries (eg, true once, false once).

The Use Case is : When a Customer has debt whose field `Paid` is `false`, this customer cannot have another debt whose field `Paid` is set to `false`.

I am aware of doctrine lifecyle prePersist, preUpdate... but none of these solve my problem.

I want `false` value to exactly exist once in the column and any attempt to insert a second false value will fail.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid that an entity constraint can only validate a constraint for that record, or "global" constraints (i.e., "only once"). Your constraint requires to read the debt table and find out a number of records and specific values. So, I think the easiest is to check your conditions when submitting the form. But also, you could check those conditions right before showing the form, and disable a widget that you already know should throw an error if selected.

Comment: Thank you for this explanation